# Editing an iframe's css (soundcloud embedded player)

Tags: javascript, css, dom, iframe, soundcloud

I've embedded a soundcloud player in to my website via iframe. I was wondering if it was possible to edit the css within the iframe and change the background colour?

iFrame link:

<
iframe width="100%" height="450" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" allow="autoplay" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?> url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/playlists/666712575%3Fsecret_token%3Ds-z7Zki&color=7b5cff&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&show_teaser=true&" visual="false""">

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible, you can only edit css inside an iframe if it is on the same domain as the parent document.